# Scaffold existing database

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I did some updates in my database, and when I want to scaffold EF Core to my database, I get this error :

> Unable to find provider assembly with name Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. Ensure the specified name is correct and is referenced by the project.

BTW I did the same thing yesterday and it worked fine, but now when I want to do it again, I get this error.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFram­eworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force
```

Comment: Have you tried using -project and/or -startupproject along with using -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Answer (score 0):

Install the following NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```